# No duplicates in jQuery Logo function

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, twitter-bootstrap-3, duplicates

I am trying to make a script to change the logo's and links of 8 logo's on the bottom of my webpage.

However my current script is creating a lot of duplicates where I only want 1 logo of the same company to be displayed at the same time.

What should I do to remove duplicates?

HTML:

```
<div class="bbe-container-wrap sponsorlogo" data-wrapper-id="TEYYD">
<div class="bbe-container container " data-container-id="IDXBz">
    <div class="row row-eq-height">
        <div class="col-md-3 img1" data-column-id="ZfWwM">
            <div class="bbe-col-content-wrap">
                <div class="bbe-component-block" data-block-id="RSyVB">
                    <a href="https://www.atvise.nl"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/huis-ter-duin-logo-hotel1-1024x768.jpg" alt=""></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 img2" data-column-id="tLyPm">
            <div class="bbe-col-content-wrap">
                <div class="bbe-component-block" data-block-id="UbKko">
                    <a href="https://www.atvise.nl"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Dental4U-300x109.jpg" alt=""></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 img3" data-column-id="lIvMg">
            <div class="bbe-col-content-wrap">
                <div class="bbe-component-block" data-block-id="ILkzc">
                    <a href="https://www.atvise.nl"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/van-der-Wiel-logo.jpg" alt=""></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 img4" data-column-id="AUEmT">
            <div class="bbe-col-content-wrap">
                <div class="bbe-component-block" data-block-id="WgxcB">
                    <a href="https://www.atvise.nl"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Booming-logo.jpg" alt=""></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-eq-height">
        <div class="col-md-3 img5" data-column-id="LMXqR">
            <div class="bbe-col-content-wrap">
                <div class="bbe-component-block" data-block-id="bleWv">
                    <a href="https://www.atvise.nl"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Horesca-logo.png" alt=""></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 img6" data-column-id="laEKc">
            <div class="bbe-col-content-wrap">
                <div class="bbe-component-block" data-block-id="cNGGz">
                    <a href="https://www.atvise.nl"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/home.png" alt=""></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 img7" data-column-id="oLIWV">
            <div class="bbe-col-content-wrap">
                <div class="bbe-component-block" data-block-id="YCAcz">
                    <a href="https://www.atvise.nl"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/happazz_logo_facebook-01.png" alt=""></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 img8" data-column-id="mIwTu">
            <div class="bbe-col-content-wrap">
                <div class="bbe-component-block" data-block-id="tjCGs">
                    <a href="https://www.atvise.nl"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/ricoh.png" alt=""></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

This is the script I made to display a random logo with link. (not happy with the lenght)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

setInterval(function(){ 
    var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
    var number2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 5);
    var item1 = $('.sponsorlogo .img'+number);
    var item2 = $('.sponsorlogo .img'+number2);

    var a1 = $(item1).find('a');
    var a2 = $(item2).find('a');

    var t1 = $(item1).find('img');
    var t2 = $(item2).find('img');

    var image = new Array ();
    image[0] = "/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Booming-logo.jpg";
    image[1] = "/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Langenegger-logo.jpg";
    image[2] = "/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/effect.png";
    image[3] = "/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Van-Duyn-van-der-Geer-Logo.png";
    image[4] = "/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/VanEgmondtotaal-logo.jpg";
    image[5] = "/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/ricoh.png";
    image[6] = "/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/advocaten.png";
    image[7] = "/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/home.png";
    image[8] = "/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/ABS-Brouwer-LOGO-TBV-WEBSITE-GALA-02.jpeg";
    image[9] = "/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Bjverhuur-logo.png";
    image[10] = "/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Brouwer-logo.jpg";
    image[11] = "/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Dental4U-300x109.jpg";
    image[12] = "/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/happazz_logo_facebook-01.png";
    image[13] = "/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Horesca-logo.png";
    image[14] = "/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/huis-ter-duin-logo-hotel1-1024x768.jpg";
    image[15] = "/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/van-der-Wiel-logo.jpg";
    image[16] = "/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/VP-Group-BMW-MINI_staand.jpg";

    var link = new Array ();
    link[0] = "#";
    link[1] = "#";
    link[2] = "#";
    link[3] = "#";
    link[4] = "#";
    link[5] = "#";
    link[6] = "#";
    link[7] = "#";
    link[8] = "#";
    link[9] = "#";
    link[10] = "#";
    link[11] = "#";
    link[12] = "#";
    link[13] = "#";
    link[14] = "#";
    link[15] = "#";
    link[16] = "#";

    var size = image.length;
    var x = Math.floor(size*Math.random());
    var x2 = Math.floor(size*Math.random());

    $(a1).attr("href", link[x]);
    $(a2).attr("href", link[x2]);
    $(t1).attr("src", image[x]);
    $(t2).attr("src", image[x2]);

}, 2000);

})
```

Comment: Sure, make it less random. Randomize first pick, then iterate past that. Or simply shuffle the array then iterate from 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably achieve the whole thing with some code like this:

```
imgs= ['08/Booming-logo.jpg','08/Langenegger-logo.jpg','08/effect.png','08/Van-Duyn-van-der-Geer-Logo.png',
       '08/VanEgmondtotaal-logo.jpg','09/ricoh.png','08/advocaten.png','09/home.png','09/ABS-Brouwer-LOGO-TBV-WEBSITE-GALA-02.jpeg',
       '09/Bjverhuur-logo.png','09/Brouwer-logo.jpg','09/Dental4U-300x109.jpg','09/happazz_logo_facebook-01.png',
       '09/Horesca-logo.png','09/huis-ter-duin-logo-hotel1-1024x768.jpg','09/van-der-Wiel-logo.jpg',
       '09/VP-Group-BMW-MINI_staand.jpg'];
lnks= ['#lnk1','#lnk2','#third','#forth','#5','#and','#so','#on','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'];

var rnd,i,vec=[]; 
for (i=imgs.length;i--;) vec[i]=i; // create a vector of same length as imgs
for (rnd=[]; rnd.push(vec.splice(Math.floor(vec.length*Math.random()),1)[0])<8;) {} 
                                   // generate 8 unique random numbers

// replace images and links in your document:
$('.bbe-component-block').each(function(i){
   $('img',this)[0].src= '/wp-content/uploads/2017/'+imgs[rnd[i]];
   $('a',  this)[0].href=lnks[rnd[i]];
})
```

The central (admittedly faily dense) line is the following:

```
rnd.push(vec.splice(Math.floor(vec.length*Math.random()),1)[0])<8
```

I get the length of `vec`, multiply that with a random number and find the next lower integer (using `Math.floor()`). I then take out the `vec`-element at that particular position and add it to the array `rnd`. For this I use the `splice()` method of the Array object. It returns an array of length 1. I extract the first element of that array (`[0]`). The return value of the `push()` method is the length of array `rnd`. I use that to check against the max length (here: 8) and stop at that point. All this is done in the first two parts of the `for` loop's condition. The actual body of the for loop is not needed (therefore: `{}`).

Comment: Thanks, works pretty good. I wanted to change only 2 of the logo but I realize that's what makes the script so complex. Perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

Some quick tips:

Filling array with same value 1 by 1 value with 1 line of code per each = come on, let a computer do the tedious work, that's what coding is all about ;)

```
for (var i = 0, i <= 16; i++){
    link[i] = '#';
}
```

Naming inconsistencies like number and number 2 but item1 and item2 should be avoided so shoudl the short and hard to remember mening behind names like X, A..  etc. unless you are using it in very limited scope (that is a function in JS), and even then use it sparingly.

Why keep using find() when you could reference by query selector directly, it's shorter and quicker to read ;)

As for your question:
you NEVER checked if that image is displayed before setting a source of another div to the same image, since its all random it's possible you have every image the same (chances are slim tho).

SOLUTION:

1. Keep an array of currently visible images or even better of available images.
2. always pick a value from that array, not simple random from interval
3. Whenever you replace image with another get into array of available images the link to image you are replacing
4. after you have chosen next image, remove that one's link as is currently used and therefore not available